# How to Test if Wifi is Working without actually connecting to a Wifi Network in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, wifi, reachability

I need to test Wifi connectivity or Wifi working status in my app.

In my current design I am using Reachability to test if user can connect to Wifi using

```
[Reachability currentReachabilityStatus] == ReachabeViaWifi
```

The issue is I do not want to test if user can connect to the internet, I have to test if there is a working Wifi in the phone. So this test only passes if a user connects to one of the Wifi networks and then gets a response from some public site. If a user is connected to 3G/WWan network this test fails.

I know I might be needing something other than Reachability to test a working wifi on an iPhone. Is there any other way please let me know.

**Note: Before marking this as a duplicate please read the text completely. My question is not about reachability to internet it is about detecting a working Wifi on an iOS device.**